# How to replace deprecated @StreamListener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot and Kafka. Migrating to latest versions of Spring Boot and others, I encountered following issue: `@StreamListener` is deprecated and removed from the library. I have a topic `my_topic` and read from it as in example below:

```
public class OrderListener {
    @StreamListener("my_topic")
    public void consumeOrder(Order order) {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

In documentation it is advised to use functional programming model. How does it look like? I found this code sample:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<Order>> consumeOrder() {
    return msg -> {
        // to get header - msg.getHeaders().get(key, valueType);
    }
}
```

Still, it's quite verbose, I like previous approach (`@StreamListener`). Is there any short modern way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

`StreamListener` is removed from the framework in preference to using `java.util.function` based programming model. If you have both input and output, that can use a `Function`; if you only have input, then use `Consumer.` Your `StreamListener` above can be re-rewritten as you did above, but if you don't want to access the headers, you do not need to wrap your payload in a `Message.` For example,

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Order> consumeOrder() {
    return order -> {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

You can provide a destination using the pattern - `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeOrder-in-0.destination`.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to provide destination in java code, not yaml/application.properties? I work with 17 kafka topics in the project

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Maybe creating a new SO thread or filing an issue in the Spring Cloud Stream repository is better.

Comment: Why would you want to couple your application so tightly to the infrastructure? The annotation-based programming modes was removed for exactly that reason?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky That's how it's done in my team so far. Tight coupling to infrastructure is ok in my case. Topic names don't change

Comment: We need to understand better how you are using 17 topics in the application. If they are dynamic destinations, Spring Cloud Stream already has a solution. Please create a GH issue in the Spring Cloud Stream repo with more details and context around your use case, and we could triage and take it from there.